# set my website as homepage for android device browser using PHP code

Tags: php, android, browser, web, device

I need to define a button on top of my website which when a user open my website with android device and click on that button, my website set as his homepage on his android device browser. I need to do this with PHP or javaScript if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think this is possible. This might lead to security issues. If this could have been possible, everybody would want to have a button like this. Lets take a scenario.

1. I open a page and click on the button.
2. The button sets a particular (unknown) page as the default homepage.
3. Next time when i open the browser, that (unknown) page does something malicious. Like an infinite loop of alert.
4. I would have to uninstall the browser to get this sorted.

However for desktop broswers, this might be possible as there are ways to fix such issues. Like opening in safe mode and changing the homepage.

P.S: You cannot do this with PHP in anyway.

Comment: its too bad :(( ty anyway